Optimizing Music Streaming App with Large Data
I have developed one music application. Where n number of songs are there under 7-8 various categories. Under "See All" section, user can able to see all available songs from that category. In some of the categories total songs are more than 300. Each song duration is about 1 to 3 hours.
I tried to add pagination but in order to add Music controls (Previous, Next song) we need all data at a time. How can I perform Optimisation for this scenario, when around 300+ data comes from API and we have to set that data.
